# Back slashes appearing when data is picked from text-area in php

Tags: php, validation

Here's what I am doing,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$text_area= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags(trim($_POST['text_area'])));
echo $text_area;
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
<input type="textarea" name="text_area" style="width:280px;height:90px" id="myTextarea"    />

<input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

But whenever I try to insert something like this: "Hello World" or 'Hello World', it outputs: \"Hello World\" or \'Hello world\'

where am I going wrong?

Comment: \ is a backslash and `/` is a forward slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you using the [mysql-real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function. Use the [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function on your data before displaying it to remove the slashes.

Comment: @JennyDcosta: no problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: How about not using `mysql_real_escape_string()` at all in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are outputting the value from the `mysqli_real_escape_string` method that escapes the string value for a SQL query to avoid SQL Injection. If you simply want to output anything that was inputted into the textarea then you can just purely show the value from the $_POST array but BEWARE if you don't do any checks you can easily fall victim to someone inputting some javascript etc. and have it appear on the page.

So for example to output just the pure text you sent to the server.

```
trim($_POST['text_area'])
```

and then you can call `mysqli_real_escape_string` again while building your query to make the string safe and avoid some common attacks.

Comment: but If I am storing it in mysql database, then i got to use mysqli_real_escape_string.. then how do i work out with that

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You escape the String to make it safe to insert into your Queries but if you are displaying the text you don't want escaped characters to show up in your output.

Comment: I think I got confused...but I understood your point..thanx johann

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mysqli_real_escape_string` incorrectly - it serves no purpose here.

Do not use it in this context, and the problem will go away. Use it only when entering data into a database.